# FTP Bluetooth and STM32F4

Tags: stm32, bluetooth

Is there a specific bluetooth module for FTP? Or any bluetooth module can be used for FTP.. Because when i see the modules they are specified as being Serial. Will HC 06 be to  FTP? If not to what to use with STM32F4 to receive a file from android device via Bluetooth?
(Q2) i am getting modules which say stereo audio transmission, can these be used

Comment: Apples and oranges

Comment: Do you realize that you can transfer a file over a 'serial' link? You don't have to implement FTP just to transfer files.

Comment: Yes, I had edited my previous question to include this question but I did it very late when all left the discussion..so asked specifically again

Comment: I guess you were talking about the bluetooth File Transfer **Profile**, not about the File Transfer Protocol based on TCP/IP. It seems a lot of users have been confused. To make your statements clear, next time, explicit your acronyms.

Comment: @brhans - can you please elaborate or any links on how do I transfer files over serial link?

Comment: In its simplest form - you open the file on one end, read bytes from it, and send them over your serial link. On the other end, you open a file to write to, receive bytes from the serial link, and write them to the file. You could investigate protocols, like XMODEM, YMODEM, ZMODEM, or whatever suits your application.

Comment: @brhans thank you. But are you talking about text files or any file like a image, .ppt etc?

Comment: The content/data in the file is irrelevant to the serial data link. A byte is a byte. The serial link doesn't know or care what that byte represents to you or your application software. Whether it's text, an image, an executable, whatever, doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @brhans so this requires me to have a special software on android which sends byte by byte..or the regular method of selecting a file and hitting send works? And on the receiving end MCU, should I have something which builds the file from packets of data? This question might be very basic, I am trying to read about it too..but if u can anwer something, it ll help

Answer (score 3):

FTP is a network protocol which must be implemented over a TCP/IP network. It is not typically used to transfer files to/from Bluetooth devices.

Transferring files to/from a Bluetooth device is usually accomplished using [the Bluetooth OBEX (Object Exchange) protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBject_EXchange).

The Bluetooth HC-06 module only supports serial communications; it does not implement OBEX. Other Bluetooth modules might, though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he was talking about the bluetooth File Transfer **Profile**, indeed related to OBEX. I agree it was very confusing, though.

Comment: @dim:Thank you very much for clearing that and yes i will take care next time. As of now i am reading based on answer here. I will come back with my project and let you all know whats going on.

Comment: @duskwuff : please let me know where to look for OBEX bluetooth, can i use the ones marked as for stereo audio transmission?

Comment: @Ajit No. Those are for Bluetooth audio.

Answer (score 2):

Read the Bluetooth specs, start with the overview: https://www.bluetooth.com/~/media/files/specification/bluetooth-quic-ref-guide.ashx?la=en

Understand your protocol stack implementation for the OSI model: https://micrium.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/OSI-Seven-Layer-Model.png

Bluetooth is a Data Link frame transfer device, and follows the 802.11 WiFi standards. You can implement IP (usually new BL devices implement IPV6/6LoWPAN) and can support applications end to end such as FTP or any of the upper layer Internet applications. FTP as other application layer functions are NOT considered network protocols.

Bluetooth is being used for many IoT devices these days so you will see many Internet protocol based implementations beyond the historical audio client usage.

Comment: @Everybody : I am not getting any specific bluetooth module which says OBEX supported. But i am getting modules which say stereo audio transmission, can these be used?